# Not able to install VLC program from .tar.xz file

Tags: software-installation, vlc, gcc, make, makefile

I successfully uncompressed the .tar.xz file and then I also ran the `./configure` command and I think it also worked. But the problem comes when I try to execute `make` command.

The given INSTALL file in the compressed file goes as follows:

```
INSTALL file for the VLC media player
=====================================

More extensive information for *nix, Windows and Mac OS X users can be
found here: http://wiki.videolan.org/Compile_VLC

People installing VLC for Windows from source MUST read:
http://wiki.videolan.org/Win32Compile

Bootstrapping VLC
=================

If you retrieved VLC from the git server and do not have yet a "configure"
script, please run:

   ./bootstrap

Configuring VLC
===============

A typical way to configure VLC is:

   ./configure

See `./configure --help' for more information.

If you intend to debug stuff, you may want to compile with debugging
symbols:

   make distclean ; ./configure --enable-debug

We recommend using GCC to build VLC, though some people reported success
with the Intel C compiler (version 8) as well. GCC version 3.3 or higher is
required. On older systems (e.g. FreeBSD 4.x), please select a more recent
version manually by setting the CC and CXX environment variables
appropriately while running the ./configure shell script.


Building VLC
============

Once configured, run `make' to build VLC.


Installing and running VLC
==========================

You can install the VLC and its plugins by typing:

   make install

But you don't need to install it if you don't want to; VLC can be launched
from the current directory as well:

   ./vlc


Building packages
=================

To build a Debian package, you need to get the packaging info
   git clone git://git.debian.org/pkg-multimedia/vlc.git debian
and then
   git-buildpackage
```

Comment: Copy/pasting a tutorial here is useless, especially the mac and win parts. What is the actual error you get when running `make`? Did you install `build-essentials` package?

Comment: sorry im new to ubuntu, how to do that??

Comment: error was: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: That `make` error suggests that the preceding `./configure` command did not complete successfully: I suggest you go back and examine its output carefully for why

Comment: Especially considering that you're new to Ubuntu I suggest you use easier and more user-friendly methods to install apps. In this case you should be able to find VLC in the Software Center, or - if you think the VLC version there is a little old - you might  just enter these commands in terminal: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily` and then `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc`.

Comment: this was the last line in configure: error: Could not find lua. Lua is needed for some interfaces (rc, telnet, http) as well as many other custom scripts. Use --disable-lua to ignore this error.

Comment: yes i know that way.. thanks Sadi, but i want to have a simple package that if I have to install a program later without internet.. so thats why

Comment: If you're new to Ubuntu why are you compiling/installing software from source? It's a relatively advanced task. You can run `sudo apt-get download vlc`. This will download VLC to your home folder in a .deb file. Double click it and install. No need to compile.

Comment: okeh i didnt knew that.. Thanks a lot Eduardo.. I am really sorry for that

Comment: Also note that if you follow one of the methods I've suggested, you can find the .deb file(s) downloaded and used to install the app in this folder: `/var/cache/apt/archives/`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about that version of `vlc` you have from `git`, I could not build that many many configuration errors, however I could build [this one](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-sources.html), from the `vlc` site.

First we need to install these

```
sudo apt-get install git libtool build-essential pkg-config autoconf
sudo apt-get build-dep vlc
```

Now get and build `vlc`

```
wget videolan.mirrors.uk2.net/vlc/2.2.1/vlc-2.2.1.tar.xz
tar xf ~/vlc-2.2.1.tar.xz
cd ~/vlc-2.2.1
./bootstrap
./configure
make
```

You can run it from here, or install it with

```
sudo make install
```

Tested on 15.10

[image]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! If this answer helped you, please click the check mark on the left to say thanks and allow others to identify the correct answer.

Comment: You are welcome, but, if it worked please click the check mark to say thanks.